# .htaccess password authentication through server-side API

Tags: api, .htaccess

I just wonder if it's possible to access a .htaccess protected directory through a server-side API? Browsers can handle the authentication well but how to do that through API?

Many thanks.

Comment: what kind of API are you talking about? if you mean with a library from a programming language: yes, i think in almost every language you will find a library capable of doing that

Comment: sorry, it's a web API.

Comment: if you cant be specific, noone can help you... i would still say its probably possible

Comment: hehe. got my head cleared. and the wonder is down to if php can get user and password stored in the .htpasswd file.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, as long as your web api provides a mechanism for you to enter the credentials to satisfy the HTTP Basic Authentication check.
For example if you are using apache httpclient in java you can use a block like the following to enter the credentials.

CredentialsProvider oCredProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
                AuthScope oAuthScope = new AuthScope(m_sServer, AuthScope.ANY_PORT, AuthScope.ANY_REALM);
                UsernamePasswordCredentials oCreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(sUsername, sPassword);
                oCredProvider.setCredentials(oAuthScope, oCreds);
                httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(oAuthScope, oCreds);

Without knowing which web api you are using, it is difficult to answer.
I would suggest you do a simple search, for example if you are trying to perform HTTP BAsic Authentication within the context of AJAX and javascript, just google 
"AJAX javascript HTTP Basic Authentication", and you will probably find a more relevant example for your specific situation.